# Python3 can't pickle _thread.RLock objects on list with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to parse the websites that contain car's properties(154 kinds of properties). I have a huge list(*name is* **liste_test**) that consist of 280.000 used car announcement URL.

```
def araba_cekici(liste_test,headers,engine):
    for link in liste_test:
        try:
            page = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
        .....
        .....
```

When I start my code like that:

```
araba_cekici(liste_test,headers,engine)
```

It works and getting results. But approximately in 1 hour, I could only obtain 1500 URL's properties. It is very slow, and I must use **multiprocessing**.

I found a result on [here](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/02/web-scraping-tutorial-python.html) with multiprocessing. Then I applied to my code, but unfortunately, it is not working.

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as multi

def chunks(n, page_list):
    """Splits the list into n chunks"""
    return np.array_split(page_list,n)

cpus = multi.cpu_count()

workers = []   
page_bins = chunks(cpus, liste_test)


for cpu in range(cpus):
    sys.stdout.write("CPU " + str(cpu) + "\n")
    # Process that will send corresponding list of pages 
    # to the function perform_extraction
    worker = multi.Process(name=str(cpu), 
                           target=araba_cekici, 
                           args=(page_bins[cpu],headers,engine))
    worker.start()
    workers.append(worker)

for worker in workers:
    worker.join()
```

And it gives:

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

I found some kind of responses with respects to this error. But none of them works(at least I can't apply to my code).
Also, I tried python multiprocess [Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) but unfortunately it stucks on **jupyter notebook** and seems this code works infinitely.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but since this question turns up when searching on Google: `multiprocessing` sends the data to the worker processes via a `multiprocessing.Queue`, which requires all data/objects sent to be [picklable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle).

In your code, you try to pass `header` and `engine`, whose implementations you don't show. (Since `header` holds the HTTP request header, I suspect that `engine` is the issue here.) To solve your issue, you either have to make `engine` picklable, or only instantiate `engine` within the worker process.